# Function not work in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<input id="CHAMPARAN EAST" 
       name="CHAMPARAN EAST" 
       onclick="SearchDistict('CHAMPARAN EAST');" type="checkbox" value="34">
```

**My Function**

```
function SearchDistict(obj) {
    debugger;
    if (obj.checked) {
        districtCollection.push(obj.value);
    } else {
        districtCollection.pop(obj.value);
        //districtCollection.splice($.inArray(obj.value, districtCollection),1);

    }
    var postData = preparingSearch();
    debugger;
    postData.StateList = '';
    postData.DistrictList = districtCollection;
    SearchEngine();
    //CallSearchBorrower(postData);
}
```

when we call SearchDistict('CHAMPARAN EAST') its work but it not invoke if    statement

Comment: only check else condition

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing id of the checkbox pass `this` object as shown below. `this` object will have all states of checkbox but just passing `id` value won't solve your purpose.

```js
 function SearchDistict(obj) 
{
        alert(obj.checked);
        if (obj.checked) 
         {
          districtCollection.push(obj.value);
         }
        else {
            districtCollection.pop(obj.value);
            //districtCollection.splice($.inArray(obj.value, districtCollection),1);

        }
        var postData = preparingSearch();
        debugger;
        postData.StateList = '';
        postData.DistrictList = districtCollection;
        SearchEngine();
        //CallSearchBorrower(postData);
    }
```

```html
<input id="CHAMPARAN EAST" 
           name="CHAMPARAN EAST" 
           onclick="SearchDistict(this);" type="checkbox" value="34">
```

above code will give you the value of `obj.checked` inside function

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is a string, not the check box, so it doesn't have the `checked` property, instead you can pass the object reference itself using `this` keyword in the line event handler.

```
<input id="CHAMPARAN EAST" name="CHAMPARAN EAST" onclick="SearchDistict(this);" type="checkbox" value="34">
```

then

```
function SearchDistict(obj) {
    debugger;
    if (obj.checked) {
        districtCollection.push(obj.value);
    } else {
        districtCollection.pop(obj.value);
        //districtCollection.splice($.inArray(obj.value, districtCollection),1);

    }
    var postData = preparingSearch();
    debugger;
    postData.StateList = '';
    postData.DistrictList = districtCollection;
    SearchEngine();
    //CallSearchBorrower(postData);
}
```